# Share Intent text using Kotlin on Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, share-intent

I want to share text in my **CardView** using share Intent using kotlin but there is a problem with last line in the code in kotlin 
the code

```
 val shareIntent = Intent()
            shareIntent.action = Intent.ACTION_SEND
            shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, "ali")
            shareIntent.type = "text/plain"
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, getResources().getText(R.string.send_to)))
```

here  is the problem in the code

```
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, getResources().getText(R.string.send_to)))
```

please help me

see the images to understand me

images

https://ibb.co/jQwYXw

https://ibb.co/id0tXw

https://ibb.co/fbCU5G

the adapter full code

```
class MyAdapter(context: Context, listItem: ArrayList<com.EliteTeam.comedytaste.Model.Movie>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {

var Context = context
var movieList = listItem;
var layoutInflator = LayoutInflater.from(context)

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup?, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {

    var inflateView = layoutInflator.inflate(R.layout.single_item, parent, false)

    return MyViewHolder(inflateView)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder?, position: Int) {

    holder?.moviewTitle?.text = movieList[position].name
    holder?.movieDescription!!.text=   movieList[position].description
    //holder!!.cardImageView!!.background=   movieList[position].image

    holder?.onclick(Context, position)
    holder!!.cardImageView.setBackgroundResource(movieList[position].image)
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {

    return movieList.size
}

class MyViewHolder(itemView: View?) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

    var moviewTitle: TextView = itemView?.findViewById(R.id.movieTitleTextView)!!
    var movieDescription: TextView = itemView!!.findViewById(R.id.movieDescriptionTextView)
    var cardImageView: CardView = itemView!!.findViewById(R.id.imageCard)
    var share: ImageButton = itemView!!.findViewById(R.id.share)

    fun onclick(context: Context, position: Int) {
        cardImageView.setOnClickListener {

    }

       share.setOnClickListener {

           val shareIntent = Intent()
         shareIntent.action = Intent.ACTION_SEND
           shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "ali")
          shareIntent.type = "text/plain"


           startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent,"send to"))

}} }}
```

Comment: What is the problem actually???

Comment: this code was work in java before i translate it to kotlin when i translate it to kotlin  it did not work

Comment: "Did not work" ..more details please

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try this :-
Use **`Intent.EXTRA_STREAM`** only when you have to send Binary data like images , if you want to sent text use  **`Intent.EXTRA_TEXT`**

```
    val shareIntent = Intent()
    shareIntent.action = Intent.ACTION_SEND
    shareIntent.type="text/plain"
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my text to send.");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent,getString(R.string.send_to)))
```

if using this code in adapter then last line should be
`context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent,getString(R.string.send_to)))`

Comment: not work createChooser(shareIntent,getString(R.string.send_to)) but when add comma after send _to) it's tell me to add sender what dose this mean createChooser(shareIntent,getString(R.string.send_to),)

Comment: I think your missing closing parentheses ) instead of comma

Comment: Just change for extra.stream to extra.text in your existing code as I explained above

Comment: Does it helps ?

Comment: yes but as I said in first command it's missing someting call sender in kotlin

Comment: i edit the question and i added images to see my problem

Comment: Where your running this code ? You have to put this code inside Activity or fragment ,it need context to run

Comment: i add the full code of the adapter contain the share code

Comment: Try this ;-  context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "send to"))

Comment: happy coding :)

Comment: Copy text ? what you want to do , copying text from view ?

Comment: yeah you know i want to put tow button in the cardview one of it share the text and the second copy the text i did the share button know i want the copy button

Comment: try this in xml view :   android:textIsSelectable="true"

Answer (score 3):

Share text in activity

```
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "shareTextHere")
    intent.type = "text/plain"
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share Via"))
```

Share text in adapter

```
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "shareTextHere")
    intent.type = "text/plain"
    context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share Via"))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use these function directly:

```
fun showSharingDialogAsKotlin(text: String) {
    val intent = Intent()
    intent.action = Intent.ACTION_SEND
    intent.type = "text/plain"
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text)
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share with:"))
}
```

Also, if you want to show your image and if you have a link:

```
fun showSharingDialogAsKotlinWithURL(text: String, url: String) {
    val intent = Intent()
    intent.action = Intent.ACTION_SEND
    intent.type = "text/plain"
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "$text: $url")
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share with:"))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use

```
context.startActivity
```

Insted of

```
startActivity
```

Comment: yup this is the solution same Suraj Nair in the comment thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly go to definition of the Start Activity and view the overloads as you are not passing one of the acceptable parameters.

What I like to do, in order to have navigation code all over the place, is to create an IntentFactory like this:

```
public class IntentFactory {

/**
 *
 * @param context
 * @return intent
 */
public static Intent getLoginIntent(Context context, boolean launchedFromNotification, boolean isApproveNotify, String idOfDetailToOpen, NewsModel notificationModel){
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, LoginActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(Globals.INTENT_KEYS.KEY_FROM_BADGE_ACCESS, launchedFromNotification);
    intent.putExtra(Globals.INTENT_KEYS.KEY_ID_OF_DETAIL_TO_OPEN, idOfDetailToOpen);
    intent.putExtra(Globals.INTENT_KEYS.KEY_IS_APPROVE_NOTIFY, isApproveNotify);
    intent.putExtra(Globals.INTENT_KEYS.KEY_ALERT_NOTIFICATION_FOR_APPROVAL, notificationModel);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    return intent;

}
/**
 *
 * @param filePath
 * @param subject
 * @param body
 * @return
 */
public static Intent getSendImageIntent(String filePath, String subject, String body){
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("image/jpg");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file://" + filePath));
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, body);
    return Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share File");

}
/**
 *
 * @param toEmailAddresses
 * @param subject
 * @param body
 * @param uris
 * @return
 */
public static Intent getEmailIntent(String[] toEmailAddresses, String subject, String body, ArrayList<Uri> uris) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
    intent.setType("text/plain");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, toEmailAddresses);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, body);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

    if(uris != null) {
        intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);

    }

    return Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send mail...");

}
/**
 * Used to launch to app details screen for toggling of permissions or other things
 * @param context
 * @return
 */
public static Intent getShowAppDetailSettingsIntent(Context context){
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + context.getPackageName()));
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);
    return intent;

}

}
```

Then you can easily manage using your StartActivity calls with

```
      String email = SharedPreferencesManager.getInstance(getContext()).getSecuredPreference(REMEMBER_ME_USER_KEY);
    String subject = getString(R.string.message) + " " + model.getFirstName() + " " + model.getLastName();
    String body = getString(R.string.subject) + model.getFirstName() + " " + model.getLastName() + "\n" + model.getShootKeyUrl();

    startActivity(IntentFactory.getEmailIntent(new String[]{email}, subject, body, null));
```

So if you align the proper parameters you will be good, but I would still recommend extracting it for ease of updating to a factory like this.